# How to Customize LoginView

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to customize the LoginView to user my Form That I created but getting an error when trying to enter the login page.
I am getting this
**TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'**.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Ghosted/Desktop/projects/helloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Ghosted/Desktop/projects/helloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Ghosted/Desktop/projects/helloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Ghosted/Desktop/projects/helloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Ghosted/Desktop/projects/helloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Ghosted/Desktop/projects/helloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Ghosted/Desktop/projects/helloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Ghosted/Desktop/projects/helloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Ghosted/Desktop/projects/helloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Ghosted/Desktop/projects/helloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func   
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Ghosted/Desktop/projects/helloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 63, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Ghosted/Desktop/projects/helloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Ghosted/Desktop/projects/helloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 133, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Ghosted/Desktop/projects/helloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 96, in get_context_data
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Ghosted/Desktop/projects/helloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 66, in get_context_data
    kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Ghosted/Desktop/projects/helloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 33, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'
```

This is the Form Created

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='',
                                widget=forms.TextInput(
                                    attrs = {
                                       'placeholder': 'username or email',
                                       }
                               ))

    password = forms.CharField(label='', 
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                                    attrs = {
                                        'placeholder': 'password'
                                    }
                                ))
```

And I want to use it in the LoginView in **django.contrib.auth.views**

In views.py

```
from .forms import LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    form_class = LoginForm
```

In urls.py:

```
path('login/', views.CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
```

Comment: Can you please post the *full* traceback?

Comment: ok would edit the question with it

Comment: What does your LoginForm class look like?

Comment: @schillingt it's in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**`LoginView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) is a view that uses a form that has been modified. That form uses a `request` parameter. You thus can not simply replace it with any other form.

You can however subclass form the [**`AuthenticationForm`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm), and then it will normally work, since you only modified the fields:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs = {
                'placeholder': 'username or email',
            }
        )
    )

    password = forms.CharField(
        label='', 
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs = {
                'placeholder': 'password'
            }
        )
    )
```