# Overriding LoginView has no effect in the registration template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I tried to add some classes to my projects login template via overriding the `LoginView` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62764034/4225972), but I seem to miss something obvious:

views.py:

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    # template_name = "registration/login.html" # standard
    form = UserLoginForm
```

forms.py:

```
class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label = "", widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {"class": "test", "placeholder": "username or email",}))
    password = forms.CharField(label = "", widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {"placeholder": "",}))
```

project.urls.py:

```
from myapp.views import CustomLoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path("home/", RedirectView.as_view(url = "/")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("myapp.urls")),
    # path("", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path("login/", CustomLoginView.as_view(), name = "login"),
]
```

login.html:

```
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit" value="login">login</button>
</form>
```

But when I open the `login/` url I can't see the `placeholder` or the `class` I added, which makes me think, that my customized form is not being used at all - I just don't understand why. I tried excluding `path("", include("django.contrib.auth.urls"))` in the `urls.py` but that had no effect. Login works fine by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `form = ...` to `form_class = ...` inside of your view.

This should work:

```py
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    # template_name = "registration/login.html" # standard
    form_class = UserLoginForm
```